# JPA and ManyToMany recursive relationship makes a bad query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In Hibernate version 5 I have a simple Entity with a recursive `ManyToMany` and when I do a `join fetch` on the relationship I get a query with two joins. I think only one join is needed. Any idea why two joins are getting generated or how to fix it?

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    @Id Integer id;    
    @ManyToMany
    protected Set<Employee> opinionCitations;
    // getters, setters
}
```

and

```
em.createQuery("select distinct e from Employee e left join fetch e.opinionCitations").getSingleResult();
```

gives me

```
select distinct 
    employee0_.id as id1_0_0_, 
    employee2_.id as id1_0_1_, 
    opinioncit1_.Employee_id as Employee1_1_0__, 
    opinioncit1_.opinionCitations_id as opinionC2_1_0__ 
from 
    Employee employee0_ 
    left outer join Employee_Employee opinioncit1_ on employee0_.id=opinioncit1_.Employee_id 
    left outer join Employee employee2_ on opinioncit1_.opinionCitations_id=employee2_.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's nothing wrong. It joins `Employee` table with the link table `Employee_Employee` and then back to `Employee`. Just like you'd expect with a `@ManyToMany`.

With a `@OneToMany` you could get away with a single join, as it doesn't require a link table, but then you'd have a tree structure which probably isn't what you want.